# How to add multiple filters (Caman.js)?

Tags: javascript, image, filter, html5-canvas, camanjs

**Im recently working with face detection algorithms, and i want to add some filters on the canvas while the detection algorithms are running.
I created a modal as you can see in FIGURE 1, which works either with sample or custom filters (Caman.js Library)**

### [image: MODAL : Filters]

When a selection is made I want to add the filters in the canvas or cancel the filters. There are 2 options:

1) CONFIRM BUTTON:

```
/* PREPARE ARRAYS */
//SAMPLE FILTERS (vintage = true sunrise = true)
var array1 = [vintage, sunrise, .../* selected values*/ ]; 

//CUSTOM FILTERS (vintage = 0.4, sunrise = 0.8) 
var array2 = [0.4,0.8, .../* selected values*/ ];
```

2) CANCEL BUTTON:

```
/* RESETS ARRAYS */
array1.length = 0;
array2.length = 0;
```

---

For now i tried to work on an image element, which works great but only by checking all the elements individually. The more filters added - the more if/else-if statements should be made:

```
if(array1.contains("vintage")){
   Caman('#myIcon', function(){
      this.vintage().render(); /*.vintage & anyFilter is in Caman.js API */
   });
}else if(array1.contains("sunrise")){
  //.....etc
}
```

---

My question:

**Is there any ways that I can pass a string value in the specific library (Caman.js), since all the filters are functions in the library and something.render() obviously will not work?**

For example:

```
function apply_Filters (*MY_FILTER_DATA*) {
    Caman('#myIcon', function(){
        this.*MY_FILTER_DATA*.render();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This [tutorial](https://tutorialzine.com/2013/02/instagram-filter-app) helped me find a solution.

### Solution:

- First add the selected filters in an array list:

  ```
  myFiltersList = [ "vintage", "filter331" ];
  ```
- For each element you should create a Caman Function and check if every filter of the list (text value) is contained in the Caman.js Library (function name). I used:

  ```
  if( array[i]   in this) statement
  ```
- This would check the text value of the filter if its contained **in this** which is in this case Caman.js. Be careful what **.this** you should be using to make this work.

  ```
  if(filtersList[i] in this) //in this  = in Caman.js
  ```
- After checking if the filter exist, the filter has to be prepared first in a specific syntax way to work:

  ```
  this[ filtersList[i] ] (); //or this["vintage"](); or this.vintage();
  ```
- Don't forget to render():

  ```
  this.render();
  ```

---

### Complete Example:

```
//For each filter in the list
myFiltersList.forEach( function() {

    //Open Caman Function and Reference the 2D canvas
    Caman('#myCanvas', function () {

        //Check if the current filter is declared within the library Caman.js
        if(myFiltersList[i] in this){

            alert("filter in the list");

            //Add filter from this as filter in Caman function/
            this[myFiltersList[i]]().render();

            i++; //Increase counter
        }else{
            alert("filter not in the list");
        }
    });
});
```

---

### Results:

**Case "vintage":**

```
alert("filter in the list");
this[myFiltersList[i]]().render();
i++;
```

**Case "filter331":**

```
alert("filter not in the list");
```